# Can a function that is undefined be lebesgue integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $a>0$.

If I have a function $f:[-a,a] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)}$ and if $g(c)=0$ for some $c\in (-a,a)$.

Is it safe to conclude that $f$ is not lebesgue integrable over $[-a,a]$ with respect to the lebesgue measure?

I would say $f$ is not integrable over $[-a,a]$ as it is undefined at $c$.

However, if we ignore $c$ in the domain then $f$ is integrable and so can we say $f$ is integrable as it is only “not integrable” on a null set?

Comment: Remember that the Lebesgue integrals will be equal for functions that agree almost everywhere. Just define $f(c)$ to be any value you want.

Comment: Does that mean if you define for the function f=1/x that f(0)=0 then f is integrable on [0,a] say?

Comment: Well, that's now a different question. It is measurable. What does it mean to say it's integrable?

Comment: Its absolute value is less than or equal to a simple integrable function

Comment: You still haven't shown that you understand the basic point. What is a simple integrable function?

Comment: A function with countable many values for which the sum of (the absolute values of the function multiplied by the measure of the preimage of the function value) is < $\infty$

Comment: Aha. There's a $<\infty$. Now, is your $f$ integrable or not?

Comment: 1/x is not integrable over [0,1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functions that are undefined at some point, that is, if $f(x):=\frac1{g(x)}$ and $g(x)=0$ for some $x$ then $f$ is not well-defined. However if you change the values of $f$ to something else, say zero, when $g$ is zero, then this new function is well-defined.

In Lebesgue integration theory we usually consider, instead of individual functions, equivalent classes of measurable functions. A class of measurable functions is a set of functions such the set of points where any two functions of this class are different is a set of zero measure, that is, if $\mathcal{L}_0(\mathbb{R})$ represent the set of Lebesgue measurable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, then for any $f\in \mathcal{L}_0(\mathbb{R})$ it equivalence class is defined by

$$
[f]:=\{h\in \mathcal{L}_0(\mathbb{R}): f(x)=h(x) \text{ almost everywhere }\}
$$

Almost everywhere means that the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\neq h(x)\}$ have zero measure. In this sense if $g$ is a measurable function and the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: g(x)=0\}$ have measure zero, then in the equivalent class of $g$, namely $[g]$, there is some function $g_1$ such that $g_1(x)=1$ whenever $g(x)=0$, therefore the equivalent class of $\frac1{g_1}$ is well-defined. So, in your example, we can consider $f$ as a representative of the class $\left[\frac1{g_1}\right]$.

Comment: Thank you. Near the ‘problem point’ the function $f$ that I’m looking at is unbounded (explodes near problem point). Would that make $f$ non-integrable still even if I redefine the problem point?. I know I strictly need to find a lower bound to $f$ that is non-integrable but for i can’t find such a lower bound function no matter what I try.

Comment: @Jaunemoto it depends on the functions. A function doesn't need to be bounded to be integrable, by example the function defined by $x\mapsto \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is Lebesgue integrable but it is unbounded.